# Can I do a backup without extension functions?

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-restore, postgresql-extensions

I use the PostGIS extension on my database. The thing is when I do a backup and then a restore, all the PostGIS functions give a warning during the restore process, because the functions already exist, as the extension is already installed.

I have to scroll through all the warning to make sure there isn't a real error.

So what is the right way to backup / restore, so I can have a clean restore process?

Comment: Why is the extension already installed on the restoration target?  Is the data already present there too?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to restore into a database that does not have PostGIS installed yet.

If PostGIS is installed in the `template1` database, use `template0` to create the new database.

Comment: But this will result on the same effect as install the extension? Specially if later you want to replace the extension for a newer version. Can you remove and install a new one ?

Comment: The dump contains a statement like `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA public;`. So restoring the dump will create the extension.

Comment: But then even if extension doesn't exist I will get the same error ? I will try and let you know. I think the only other way would be I uninstall the extension before do the backup and then reinstall

Comment: Dropping the extension in the original database would drop all columns that use PostGIS data types. All you need is the extension files installed at the destination so that the `CREATE EXTENSION` succeeds.